# How to show the two different data in autocomplete textView data

Tags: android, autocomplete

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+dbh.AM_Name+" FROM "+dbh.TABLE_ACCMST, null);
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
            names.add(cur.getString(0));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dropdownlist, R.id.checkedTextView1, names);
        etsebuyname.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the above code I am populating the autocomlete TextView with the names present in my database. I want to display respective city from the database along with the name in the dropdown help. But after slection only name should be filled in the AutoCompletetextview. Please help.

Comment: after selection split the string

Answer (score 0):

Get the string by using the id clicked in the drop down list, then split  the string with a separator, I mostly put -$- in my strings to separate them. Then find the Text View and just use the set text Method.

Comment: which listner should I use to fire split event.

Comment: No listeners just use the .split function